# Unable to generate bundle inside static library

Tags: ios, objective-c, bundle, static-libraries

I followed the tutorial http://www.seifeet.com/2014/08/ios-coredata-as-static-library.html and I get an error that says my bundle is missing when I try compiling. I downloaded the source and got the same problem.

The error I got was:

> "error: /Users/MY_USERNAME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SFTwoButtonLayout-arwyiyjaammyrwcedmnwmvatexok/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/sfdatamodels.bundle: No such file or directory"

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When do you get the error? Update your question with the code causing the error.

Comment: @rmaddy I get the error when I compile the source code I got from the tutorial. I don't know exactly what is causing the error. I believe it's a configuration issue of the static library.

Comment: @rmaddy I removed sfdatamodels.bundle from the target SFTwoButtonLayout's Build Phase under Copy Bundle Resouces and I was able to compile, but When I crashed immediate when I click on a button in the app to use core data. sfdatamodels.bundle is needed for the app to function, but the app doesn't compile with it inside Copy Bundle Resources of my Build Phases.